# No Dropbox top panel icon since update to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dropbox

Since updating to Ubuntu 18.04 I've lost my Dropbox top panel icon. It is not displayed wrong but it doesn't appear at all.

I tried this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1032789/26022) as well as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030775/26022) with no success.